# Is the metaplectic group not a matrix group - counterexample

Tags: symplectic-group, clifford-algebras, rt.representation-theory

Is the statement below false?

"The metaplectic group Mp2(R) is not a matrix group: it has no faithful finite-dimensional representations."

---

Possible "counterexample":
Sp(2n,R) is a subgroup of O(4n,C) (or O(2n,2n) if you prefer).
So the Clifford algebraic Pin group will contain a double cover. The double cover will definitely be disconnected if Sp(2n,R) is not a subgroup of SO(4n,C). It should be connected if it is entirely in the Spin subgroup of the Pin group.

Consider the case of Sp(2,R). If we have a 2x2 real matrix with determinant 1, we can establish an isomorphism in SO(4,C) as follows: a^2-b^2-c^2+d^2 = 1
[a+b,c-d;c+d,a-b]  <--->  [a,-bi,-ci,-d;bi,a,d,-ci;ci,-d,a,bi;d,ci,-bi,a]

Since Spin(4,C) will double cover SO(4,C), we could have a connected double cover of Sp(2,R).

---

Note: The proposed "example" is false due to submitted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could include details of your proposed counterexample?

Comment: This question is written in an argumentative tone of voice, which risks turning people off. I recommend that you revise it, taking into consideration advice from http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask. Among other things, you could post your putative faithful finite-dimensional representation. At the minimum, writing up your construction carefully will probably lead you to find an error.

Comment: Sorry about that. I hope this is better for everyone.

Comment: @Alexander Schlering: You're just constructed the disconnected double cover of the symplectic group inside of the disconnected Pin group. This has nothing to do with the metaplectic group, and is not useful.  Be more attentive to the importance of checking connectedness.

Comment: Thanks kreck. I have altered the question. Now I need to show that indeed it is a subgroup of the full Pin group and not the Spin group.

Comment: -1 for persisting despite Theo's explanation (and any number of sources which state that the metaplectic group is not a matrix group)

Comment: Theo Johnson Floyd has already $completely$ answered the question. The issue is the following: suppose $G$ is  an algebraic group defined over $\mathbb R$ such that the complex algebraic group $G(\mathbb C)$ is simply connected. (Then $G(\mathbb R)$ is cnnected) and any continuous representation of the universal cover of $G(\mathbb R)$ factors through a representation of $G(\mathbb R)$. This is proved in Helgason's book. If we take $G=SO(n)$, then $G(\mathbb C)$ is not simply connected, so the above argument does not apply; if we take $G$ to be a real form of $Spin (n)$, then it does.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keep in mind that any finite-dimensional representation of a Lie group determines a finite-dimensional representation of its Lie algebra, and for a connected Lie group the induced Lie algebra representation determines the Lie group representation.

However, every finite-dimensional representation of $\operatorname{Lie}(\mathrm{Mp}(2,\mathbb R)) = \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$ comes from a representation of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$, and so does not come from a faithful rep of $\mathrm{Mp}(2,\mathbb R)$. One way to see this by directly classifying all finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$ representations, which is not too difficult.  A better way is to observe that any $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$-representation $V$ embeds in an $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$-representation $V \otimes \mathbb C$, but $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ is simply connected, so $V \otimes \mathbb C$ is a representation of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$, and so the $\mathrm{Mp}(2,\mathbb R)$-representation that gave rise to $V$ factors through $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$, and on the other hand the map $\mathrm{Mp}(2,\mathbb R) \to \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb C)$ factors through $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ and is not faithful.

Comment: Hi! Where can I read more about this concept of group representations factoring?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Theo seems to be right. Nevertheless, it is not explained that "the Mp(2,R)-representation that gave rise to V factors through SL(2,C) and on the other hand Mp(2,R) -> SL(2,C) factors through SL(2,R)". This cannot be true in general. E.g. in the case of SO(n) and Spin(n), i.e., when SL(2,R) is replaced by SO(n) and Mp(2,R) by Spin(n). Note that  Spin(n,C) is (as SL(2,C)) simply connected as well (so topologically, it works). I think a bit incomplete part of the answer - for me - can be in factorizations related to the complexifications. (SO(n) is a compact real of SO(n,C), but SL(n,R) is split real of SL(n,C) - this should explain the difference bteween the SO and Sp-cases).

Comment: why is this an answer? this should be in the comments.

Comment: I do not have reputation high enough. I should post is as an question and hope that it would not be linked to the asnwer I actually make a comment on, as You noticed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Venkataramana above. Which book of Helgason is meant in the comment?

Comment: There is a book by Helgason on "differential geometry, Lie Groups and symmetric spaces" and in one of the exercises in the latter chapters, this particular point is stressed.

Comment: Don't you know a precise reference, please?